# Copy data from an SD card to a raw file

Tags: android

How might I copy data from an SD card to a raw file?

Comment: Programmatically or in general?

Comment: Programmatically.By raw file i mean the raw folder i have created in eclipse .

Answer (score 2):

Use  [ADB](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html) tool to pull data from the device/emulator. See the PUSH and PULL operations.

Example:

```
adb pull /sdcard/test.txt test.txt
```

Pull pulls a file from your Android device to your desktop computer.